# How to bind the content to restful service's body to post it to the server?

Tags: web-services, rest, angularjs

How do I send JSON as BODY in a POST request to server from my angular page?
I found something like we need to bind it to the service body, but don't know how to bind?
Any help?           Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#post) is fairly complete. Using `$http.post(url, data)` and putting inside "data" whatever JSON stuff you want to send in the body should do it.

It looks to obvious so it might be that i misuderstood your question. Id that's the case, please explain a little more!!!